# How to create a iterative condition inside np.where?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have dataframe `df` and columns list `cols_list` which need to check the condition.

ex: `cols_list = [cols1, cols2, col3]`

I need to create new column as shown below,

`df['new_col'] = np.where((df['cols1'] == 1) | (df['cols1'] == 1) | (df['cols1'] == 1), 1, 0)`

I have multiple `cols_list` with different length, How can I create this condition `(df['cols1'] == 1) | (df['cols1'] == 1) | (df['cols1'] == 1)` iteratively for multiple `cols_list`?

Currently, I need to do it manually, as those kind of `cols_list` are in hundreds, I was looking for a better way to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
np.where((df[cols_list].eq(1).any(axis=1), 1, 0))
```

Comment: Here `any` will work same as `|` and if I use `all` that will be similar to `&`. Is assumption is correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct